# StrongSwan - ipsec pki command

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I would like to know why the first time I run the "ipsec pki" command to get a private key this key is generated quickly, but the next time you try to run the same command to get this key because you have deleted the old one it takes about 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its default configuration [pki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecPKI)'s `--gen` command generates RSA keys using the *random* and *gmp* plugins. Since the *random* plugin reads from `/dev/random` this might take a while as that device blocks (i.e. does not return any data) if the system's entropy pool is exhausted.

The [wiki page of the `--gen`](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecPkiGen) command describes possible workarounds, one is configuring the *random* plugin to use `/dev/urandom` (which does not block), another is switching to a different plugin to generate the keys (e.g. the *openssl* plugin).